# Do I need to install NVIDIA drivers if I have an integrated graphics card?

Tags: drivers, graphics

I have a laptop with NVIDIA GTX graphics card and Intel Skylake integrated video card. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with NVIDIA drivers installed. In PRIME Profiles of NVDIA X Server Settings I select Intel to disable the NVIDIA card, right in order to optimize the power consumption of the laptop.

The integrated card is enough for my needs and it adds a lot to my battery life, so my question is, do I actually need to install the NVIDIA drivers? Do drivers do something to disable the card, or is it never brought up if there are no drivers?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need Nvidia drivers to install `nvidia-prime` that will power off the Nvidia adapter.

If you don't have `nvidia-prime` both adapters will consume power, and you will also have graphics glitches too.

Another option is to use an opensource `bumblebee`, but it does not work well on the modern releases.

I see no problem in installing Nvidia drivers for that purpose.

You have the drivers installed, so keep using them.

Comment: So basically, the answer is YES, you need to have the graphics drivers installed to properly disable the card.

Is my assumption correct, that with nvidia-prime you also need nvidia-settings and nvidia-XXX (XXX being version driver num)?

Comment: `nvidia-settings` is not quite necessary if it is not a strict dependency of `nvidi-XXX`. You can switch the nvidia in CLI. But you need the driver to get `nvidia-prime` working.

Comment: Can you point to some more technical explanation of why do you need to install the driver just to disable the card, otherwise it is still somehow in use?

Comment: You can search it yourself. The problem is that the open source `nouveau` driver can't switch off the power of Nvidia adapters. You need either `nvidia-prime` that is proprietary, or `bbswitch` from the `bumblebee` project.

Comment: it seems that nvidia-prime, nvidia-settings and bbswitch-dkms are dependencies :

Comment: nvidia-prime and bbswitch are recommends, not dependemcies.

Comment: I installed nvidia-prime, nvidia-settings and bbswitch-dkms
lsmod shows i915 (no nvidia, no nouveau)

but this shows unknown:
prime-select query --> unknown
but this is probably not related

Comment: Still not 100% sure if this is doing power-saving for my nvidia card